# Is $\cos\theta$ or $\sin\theta$ an increasing function in first quadrant?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

The question asks whether $\sin\theta$ is increasing function in first quadrant or $\cos\theta$ is increasing function in first quadrant. Other options are $e$ and $e^x$. I think the answer is $\sin\theta$ because if we put the values of angles from $0^{\circ}$ to $90^{\circ}$ the answer goes from $0$ to $1$. But the answer at the back of the book is $\cos\theta$. Am I taking this in wrong way? Or the answer is wrong? I just want to confirm it. Should I derivate it?

Comment: $\cos \theta$ is *decreasing* in the first quadrant. $e^x$ is always increasing, $e$ is constant.

Comment: Hey, could you post the full question?

Comment: @Andrew That is the full question. It is actually an MCQ.

Comment: How is $e^x$ an always increasing funtion? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Ah ok. In that case, what Zain said. Book is wrong!

Comment: The derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ (which is positive for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: But $e^x$ does not depend on $\theta$ so is not increasing in $\theta$

Comment: Got it. One more thing why can't be the answer $\sin\theta$ as it is increasing in first quadrant and the question asks for the first quadrant only.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the question correctly? Is the MCQ asking for a decreasing or increasing function?

Comment: Increasing only

Comment: what @smcc said proves that $e^x$ cannot be the answer. I guess $\sin\theta$ is the right choice. Book is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^x$ is strictly increasing on R...$\cos\theta $ is decreasing in first quadrant...so the answer must be $\sin\theta$..

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment, but I wanted to make sure that everybody saw it:

In the first quadrant, the “co” functions all are decreasing, and the “non-co” functions all are increasing.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks